# Meaning of "the scales begin to tip"

Tags: idiom-meaning

I could not find the meaning of "the scales begin to tip" in online dictionaries.

Here is the sentence:

"Every era has a moment when the scales begin to tip." The next sentence is "That moment has come for the world's transgenders".

Could you please rephrase the first sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tip the scales](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tip+the+scales), also *tip the balance:*

> - to cause a change, esp. in making something more likely to happen.
>
>   - *She says the city's reputation helped tip the scales/balance when the company was deciding whether to move the factory.*
>       (Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright.)

The reference is to  *scales* which may measure weight (metaphorically) in favour of something.

- Every era has a moment  when things begin to change. 
  [image]